# Сравнение числа по одной цифре c++

Tags: c++, for, сравнение

Делаю всем известную игрушку "Угадай число". Единственный момент, она должна после каждого предположения писать сколько чисел угадано и сколько на своих местах(число трехзначное, к примеру)
Не получается правильно сделать функцию, которая сравнивает каждую введенную цифру в числе с сгенерированными. Проблема в функции ugadal(). Код целиком: (да, знаю, что переменные так лучше не называть, просто для понимания =) )

```
constexpr auto RANGE = 3;
int x;
int vveli[5];
int comp[5];
int computer();
int comp_num = computer();
int count(int x, int vveli[5], int RANGE);
int place(int vveli[5], int comp[5]);
int ugadal(int vveli[5], int comp[5]);

int computer()
{
    srand(time(NULL));
    int generation = 100 + rand() % ((999 + 1) - 100);
    return(generation);

}

int count(int x, int vveli[5], int RANGE)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < RANGE; i++)
    {
        int step = pow(10, (RANGE - i));
        vveli[i] = (x % step) / pow(10, (RANGE - 1 - i));
    }
    return(0);
}

int place(int vveli[5], int comp[5])
{
    int position = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < RANGE; i++)
    {
        if (vveli[i] == comp[i])
            position++;
    }
    return(position);
}

int ugadal(int vveli[5], int comp[5])
{
    int total = 0;
  
    for (int i = 0; i < RANGE; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < RANGE; j++) // ближе всего - без этой строчки
        if (vveli[i] == comp[j])
            total++;

    }

    return(total);
}
int main()
{
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "Russian");
    printf("Загадано число с %d цифрами, поехали\n", RANGE);
    printf("Подсказка...: %d\n", comp_num);
    count(comp_num, comp, RANGE);

    do
    {
        puts("Ваш вариант:");
        scanf_s("%d", &x);
        int O = x / pow(10, RANGE - 1);
        if (O == 0 || O > 10)
            printf("Введите число с %d цифрами\n", RANGE);
        else {
            count(x, vveli, RANGE);
            printf("Угадано: %d., На своих местах: %d\n", ugadal(vveli, comp), place(vveli, comp));
        }
    } while (ugadal(vveli, comp) < RANGE || place(vveli, comp) < RANGE);
    puts("Верно! ");
    return 0;
}
```

Сначала кажется, что работает как нужно, но в ситуации, когда загадано, к примеру 761, вводим 777 - программа выдает 3 угаданных числа

Comment: Почему бы не использовать string? Просто в самой функции создаешь отдельные переменные (сгенерированного/введенного числа) с помощью to_string и сравниваешь их посимвольно. Думаю идея понятна

Comment: @Artyomka, или идея неудачно сформулирована, или Вы не поняли правила. Там, фактически, нужно два сравнения: найти цифры, присутствующие в загаданном числе, и те из них, которые на своих местах.

Comment: Что касается функции ```ugadal```, то можно попробовать в массиве ```comp``` заменять совпавший элемент на ```-1```, например. Это позволит Вам избежать ситуации, приведенной в вопросе. Но кроме того, мне  кажется, что у Вас ошибка в логике. Скажем, если загадано ```761```, а ввели ```167```, то ```ugadal``` вернет 3 совпадения (что правильно) и цикл игры закончится

Comment: @ЮрийКозлов я об этом же), с двумя строками легче работать (по индексам), нежели через остаток

Comment: @Artyomka да, соглашусь. Через строку проще. Но автору больше переделывать :) Пусть сначала уж на имеющемся отладит логику сравнений, чтобы у него подсчет верных цифр правильно шел

Comment: @ЮрийКозлов, да, на счет неверной логики согласен, поэтому и спросил=) Думал не вижу какого-то очевидного варианта через те же циклы. Так как имеющимся циклом он сравнивает значения по очереди( проверяет равна ли введенная 1 цифра числа, первой цифре числа, сгенерированного другой функцией)

Comment: Первые цифры, потом вторые, потом третьи у Вас сравнивает функция ```place```. А ```ugadal``` сравнивает первую цифру введенного со ВСЕМИ загаданного, потом вторую со всеми и т.д....

Comment: А что надо ответить в вашем случае? 761 а введено 777 - надо один или три? Каждая из семерок формально годится. А 767 и 777? Нужна точная постановка задачи. Кстати, в настоящих "быках и коровах" числа четырехзначные, и повторения цифр ни в запросах, ни в угадываниях не разрешены. Кстати, посмотрите вот [это](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/search?q=%D0%B1%D1%8B%D0%BA%D0%B8+%D0%B8+%D0%BA%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D1%8B).

Comment: @Mikhailo суть задачи, чтобы программа выводила количество угаданных цифр и количество цифр на своих местах. На том же примере: загадано - 761, вводим - 777, программа должна выдать: угадано 1(цифра 7 есть в загаданном числе в количестве одной штуки) на своих местах 1( цифра 7 на позиции первой цифры). Ps вот здесь на 182 странице аналогичная задача решается, но на практике такое решение не работает https://studfile.net/preview/5397800/page:19/

Answer (score 0):

[Вот это](https://ideone.com/Ea21Ep) вроде работает:

```
pair<int, int> check(int value, int guess) {
    pair<int, int> r{0, 0};
    int vd[10] = {0}, gd[10] = {0};

    while (value || guess) {
        int dv = value % 10, dg = guess % 10;

        if (dv == dg) {
            r.first++;
            r.second++;
            }
        else {
            vd[dv]++;
            gd[dg]++;
            }

        value /= 10;
        guess /= 10;
        }

    for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i)
        if (vd[i]) {
            if (gd[i]) r.second += min(vd[i], gd[i]);
            }

    return r;
    }
```

Первый член пары - сколько на местах, второй - сколько угадано.

Answer (score 0):

Как уже здесь писали, через строки пойти действительно во много раз проще:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <ctime>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <Windows.h>
#include <set>

using namespace std;

void init()
{
    srand(time(NULL));
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "Russian");
    SetConsoleCP(1251);
    SetConsoleOutputCP(1251);
}

int chtoi(char ch)
{
    return ch - '0';
}

void guessCheck(int number, int guess)
{
    while (true)
    {
        if (to_string(guess).length() != to_string(number).length())
        {
            cout << endl << "Количество цифр в загаданном числе и предположении игрока не совпадают. Повторите ввод: ";
            cin >> guess;
        }
        else
            break;
    }
}

void guessComparePosition(int number, int guess)
{
    int cnt = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < to_string(number).length(); i++)
    {
        if (to_string(number)[i] == to_string(guess)[i])
            cnt++;
    }
    cout << "Подсказка: " << cnt << " чисел находятся на своём месте." << endl;
}

void guessCompareNumber(int number, int guess)
{
    int cnt = 0;
    set<int> number_set;
    set<int> guess_set;
    for (int i = 0; i < to_string(number).length(); i++)
    {
        number_set.insert(chtoi(to_string(number)[i]));
        guess_set.insert(chtoi(to_string(guess)[i]));
    }
    set<int>::iterator it_number = number_set.begin();
    for (int i = 0; i < number_set.size(); i++)
    {
        set<int>::iterator it_guess = guess_set.begin();
        for (int j = 0; j < guess_set.size(); j++)
        {
            if (*it_number == *it_guess)
                cnt++;
            it_guess++;
        }
        it_number++;
    }
    cout << cnt << " уникальные цифры числа отгаданы верно." << endl;
}

void guessNumber(int number)
{
    cout << "Попробуйте угадать число. Введите предположение: ";
    int guess;
    cin >> guess;
    guessCheck(number, guess);
    while (true)
    {
        if (guess == number)
        {
            cout << endl << "Поздравляем, вы угадали! Загаданным числом было " << number << endl;
            break;
        }
        else
        {
            cout << endl << "Вы не угадали!" << endl;;
            guessComparePosition(number, guess);
            guessCompareNumber(number, guess);
            cout << "Попробуйте угадать ещё раз: ";
            cin >> guess;
            guessCheck(number, guess);
        }
    }
}

int main()
{
    int number = rand() % 1001;
    cout << "Игра начинается! Загадано число из " << to_string(number).length() << " цифр." << endl;
    guessNumber(number);
    return 0;
}
```

Открыт для вопросов и критики, если таковые возникнут.

Comment: Согласен на счет строк, спасибо! Но остается момент с тем, что программа должна выводить еще и количество угаданных цифр И с работой этой функции все еще проблема... ну или я совсем не уловил идею)) Я сделал так [ https://onlinegdb.com/K1FxJ7Wch ] -- функция guessMatch в теории должна выводить количество угаданных цифр в сгенерированном числе

Comment: Действительно, не увидел, что требуется ещё и подсчитывать угаданные цифры. Обновил код, теперь реализован вроде как весь функционал. Самое простое, что я придумал для подсчёта уникальных цифр, - это контейнер типа <set> (множество)

Comment: А не проще `int chtoi(char ch) { return ch-'0'; }`? В целом же - очень неэффективный код... :( Ну вот например, зачем для каждой цифры переводить число в строку? Почему не сделать это один раз? ну и тд и тп...

Comment: да тоже подумал, что довольно сложно для этой задачки. ну и даже при таком варианте остаются "баги" по типу: загадано-897, вводим-777, результат: 0 цифр на своем месте

Comment: Насчет `int chtoi(char ch) { return ch-'0'; }` я не знал, сам ещё учусь, так что спасибо за лайфхак)) Что касается ошибки по типу "загадано 897, вводим 777 -> 0 цифр на своем месте", то я это поправил. Проблема была в функции guessComparePostition, в строке `for (int i = 0; i < to_string(number).length(); i++)`. Я почему-то там указал в диапазоне `to_string(number).length() - 1`, теперь же работает все как надо

Answer (score 0):

В общем, получился вот такой вот финальный вариант через строки. Все "баги" вроде исправил: числа генерируются каждый раз случайно, угаданные числа распознаются корректно, позиции также верно подсчитывает

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <ctime>
#include <algorithm>
using namespace std; 

int getRandom() {
    
    srand(time(NULL));
    int generation = 100 + rand() % ((999 + 1) - 100);
    return(generation);
}

int input() {
    int n{0};
    while (n < 100 || n > 999) {
        cout << "Введите число: ";
        cin >> n;
        if (n < 100 || n>999)
            cout << "Введите число из 3 цифр!"<< endl;
        
    }
    return n;
}
    
int main()
{
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "Russian");
    int test = getRandom();
    cout << "Компьютер загадал трехзначное число, поехали!\n";
    cout << "Подсказка..." << test << std::endl;
    int num{ 0 };
    while (true) {
        num = input();
        string s_test = to_string(test);
        string s_num = to_string(num);
        int guess{ 0 }; 
        int pos{ 0 };
        for (size_t i{ 0 }; i < s_test.length(); ++i) 
        {
            auto includes = find(s_num.begin(), s_num.end(), s_test[i]);
            includes != s_num.end() ? ++guess : guess += 0;

            for (size_t j{ 0 }; j < s_num.length(); ++j) 
            {
                if (s_test[i] == s_num[j] && i == j) ++pos;
            }
        }
        if (num == test) 
            break;
        
        cout << "Угадано: " << guess << ". На своем месте: " << pos << '\n';
    }
    cout << "\n *ВЫ УГАДАЛИ*: ";
    return 0;
}
```